# Twisted Python - If deferred goes out of scope, will it ever be fired?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

If I create a Deferred and add some callbacks to it while in the reactor event loop, will it ever be called if I let the local reference go out of scope?  For example, if I have a protocol with a `connectionMade()` like so:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    # This made up function returns a deferred that will connect to 
    # some remote server using some made up protocol and return some data.
    d = connectToRemoteServer(reactor, url)
    d.addCallback(self._handleRemoteConnection)
    # At this point, d is going to go out of scope, so will the deferred
    # it points to ever get fired?

def _handleRemoteConnection(self, data):
    # Do something with the data
```

I have seen this pattern in different code that uses Twisted, and I am having trouble understanding why the deferred that is returned from `connectToRemoteServer()` is not 
garbage collected when d goes out of scope.  I would think it would never fire, or maybe fail randomly due to a race condition.  Can anyone explain to me why this works?  I have read http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html a couple times, but I still am not sure why this would work?

Thanks,

Carl

Comment: Objects are garbage-collected when there are no references to them. Therefore, `d` is not the only reference to the object, since it is not garbage-collected. Add a `print(sys.getrefcount(d))`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothetical `connectToRemoteServer` API is going to hold a reference to `d` internally, usually with a reference from the global `reactor` to an object which will fire `d` (by calling `d.callback`) when the operation represented by `d` is complete.

So the reference goes from the stack, to the stack frame for `reactor.run` (because the reactor is running), to `d`.